# Is there a way to see what cards have been collected without actually playing a game of Rage Frenzy?

Tags: rage

I'm playing through a level, and I have a couple different saves. I want to be sure that I picked up a card on my way through, but since the way back is blocked I cannot go back and physically check. Is there a way to see what cards are in my deck? I'd rather not replay the level just to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can only look at your deck when you are at a card table. Talk to the dealer to start a game, then look at your cards on the deck building screen. Then quit, and no money should have changed hands.

Comment: This isn't the answer I was hoping for, but it does appear to be correct. Nice workarond!

Comment: _RAGE_ has a clumsy UI, this is the best I can suggest. I'm personally still irritated that there is no world map.